# I am having trouble getting a search result with requests in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get search results with requests in python, but it is not returning any results. I can see the information has been passed to the page but it's not sending any back.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rego = "1hdv242"
#plate = {'plate' : rego}


url = 'https://online.transport.wa.gov.au/webExternal/registration/?1-1.IBehaviorListener.1-layout-layout_body-registrationRequestForm-id7_hf_0=&plate=1hdv242&searchButton=16'
response = requests.post(url, data = {'plate': '1hdv242'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
data = [item.text for item in soup.select('.data')]

#print(data)

print(soup)
```

This is the code i am using

This is where i can see the rego has been passed to the page

```
<ol>
<li>
<span class="emphasized-plain">Plate number:</span>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
# # # <input id="id1" maxlength="15" name="plate" onchange="var wcall=wicketAjaxPost('./;jsessionid=SwzIYkP1Lh9XDh-k4XDn_GQCD2-vmQ-xKm-aBlu89OPIaD-XMkRs!1563753950!-1720409949?0-1.IBehaviorListener.2-layout-layout_body-registrationRequestForm-plate', wicketSerialize(Wicket.$('id1')),function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('id1') != null;}.bind(this));" title="Please enter your plate number here" type="text" value="1HDV242"/>
</div>
</li>
<li>
```

Last line 1hdv242 is the passed rego

So what I am trying to retrieve is the form that is returned once the request has been submitted. The form contains the details of the car and date of registration expiry.

```
</div>
```

Vehicle licence expiry date request results      
    
    
        
            
                Plate Number
                1HDV242
            
            
                Make
                KIA
            
            
                Model
                RIO
            
            
                Year
                2020
            
            
                Colour
                BLACK
            
            
                This vehicle licence expires on
                12/02/2023

```
       </div>
```

For some reason I can't get to the page that displays this

Comment: What information do you want to extract from this page?? Can you add expected output.

Comment: Hi I am looking to grab the output from the search that should be the details of the car and date of rego expiry